# error on print by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i have ajax request to other page to print something on printer, but when i call function i cannot print the page

ajax code :

```
/******* Print A6 ********/
function ButtonClickHanlder( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var bills_ID = $('#bills_ID').val();
        $.post("Bills/BillsPrintA6.php", { bills_ID: bills_ID },
            function(data){
                //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            }
        );
    }

    $(function(){

        $('#printA6').click(ButtonClickHanlder);
    });
/***************/
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that when you go to print the data isn't loaded. You'll probably need to have the ajax fire before you send it to the printer.